# UnhandledException in windows service c#

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-services

Im having some real trouble. I really hope that someone is able to help me out here.

I've got a Windows Service, which is supposed to run with a certain frequence.
My Service communicates with some webservices from our suppliers.

My problem  is making my service robust, in case those services are unavailable, due to breakdown etc.

I've tried to control this with a try catch.

```
/***************************************************************************************************/
/* Code snippet: Unable to compile. (it says: The name 'xyz' does not exist in the current context)*/
try  
{
  var xyz = new xyz.ExternalService().GetRelevantData();
}

catch(Exception e)
{
  ...handle the exception
}
/* Code snippet: Unable to compile. (it says: The name 'xyz' does not exist in the current context)*/
/***************************************************************************************************/
```

But the compiler won't accept this (it says: The name 'xyz' does not exist in the current context), hense I need another solution.
I bumped into currentDomain.UnhandledException and I would like to use this functionality.
Unfortunately I can't get this to handle the exception.

Can anyone help me regarding a solution?

Regarding the code below with the division by zero, it's my intension to replace the division with:

```
var xyz = new xyz.ExternalService().GetRelevantData();
```

I belive that would solve my problem.

```
/*********************************************************************/
/* Code snippet: currentDomain.UnhandledException : Division by zero.*/

    public void divisionbyzero()
    {
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);

        int i = 0;
        int m = 12;
        double x = 0;
        try
        {
            x = m * i;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            writeToLog(e.ToString());                
        }
        x = m / i;
    }
/*********************************************************************/
/* Code snippet: currentDomain.UnhandledException : Division by zero.*/
```

I would like to catch the exception with the 'UnhandledException', when the division is done.
But unfortunately this doesn't happen.

New section with code context below:
I hope this makes sense:

```
/*****************************************************************/        
/****Code snippet: called from Windows service OnTimedEvent *****/        
    static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
        File.AppendAllText("C:\\lab\\logs\\log.txt", "" + e.Message + ""); 
    }

    private void writeToLog(Exception e)
    {
        File.AppendAllText("C:\\lab\\logs\\log.txt", "" + e.Message + "");
    }

    public void divisionbyzero() // this is called in Windows service in OnTimedEvent.
    {

        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);


        int ii = 0;
        int mm = 12;
        double xx = 0;
        try
        {
            xx = mm * ii;
        }
        catch (Exception excep)
        {
        File.AppendAllText("C:\\lab\\logs\\log.txt", "" + excep.ToString() + ""); 
        }

        xx = mm / ii; // This is the exception I would like (currentDomain.UnhandledException) to handle
    }
/****Code snippet: called from Windows service OnTimedEvent ************/        
/***********************************************************************/
```

I've been searching the internet: This guy has the same problem, you may want to read this: http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/getting-appdomainunhandledexception-74589.aspx

Comment: _"But the compiler won't accept this"_ - what was the error?

Comment: It would help if you post exact code and compiler error but...as blind guess: you're declaring xyz (var xyz = ...) inside try/catch then it's not visible outside it (or you re-declare it inside try/catch and you already declared it outside).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Im not re-declaring. Im only declaring once.
But Im only able to make that particular declaration with out try-catch.
So how do I handle an exception due to a failure when declaring?

Comment: "compiler won't accept this, hence I need another solution" No. You don't. You need to figure out why the accepted way of dealing with exceptions is not working out for you. Giving up and inventing some round-the-houses cocktail of exception handling will lead to rotten code that is impossible to maintain.

Comment: @LarsHansen we can't discuss about a compile-time error if you don't provide both exact error and exact code to reproduce it. Also CurrentDomain.UnhandledException doesn't work? Why not? Code code code

Comment: If you want to catch an exception, you need to wrap try/catch around the part that is throwing the exception. In this case, it's a divide. In your code, the division does not have try/catch around it.

Comment: @Micky: (it says: The name 'xyz' does not exist in the current context)

Comment: @spender: Well I believe you have a point. But how?
The program is based on that code, so Im not that happy rewriting...

Comment: @spender: I would like the division to be handled by the 'UnhandledException' NOT the try catch.

Comment: @spender: I've been searching the internet: This guy has the same problem, you may want to read this: http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/getting-appdomainunhandledexception-74589.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

```
var xyz = new xyz().ExternalService();
try  
{
    xyz.GetRelevantData();
}

catch(Exception e)
{
    ...handle the exception
}
```

Thanks for all your posts :-).

Answer (score 1):

You need below code to create instance:

```
var xyz = new xyz().ExternalService().GetRelevantData();
```

Now `xyz` would be treated as a function! And i guess you are having that function in your code!

Then put it as below:

```
try  
{
  var xyz = new xyz().ExternalService().GetRelevantData();
}

catch(Exception e)
{
  ...handle the exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So it looks, from your comments, that this is your problem:

```
try  
{
  var xyz = new xyz.ExternalService().GetRelevantData();
}

catch(Exception e)
{
  //but I want to use xyz here
  ...handle the exception
}
```

So, define `xyz` in a higher scope, so it's visible in the `catch`;

```
var xyz = new Xyz();
try
{
    var someValue = xyz.DoSomething();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //xyz is still visible here.
}
```

Comment: regarding var xyx, the class is defined by: 

public partial class xyzClass: object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
...

}
Im worryied if this code dumps if there isn't contact with the server.
Am I wrong?